# Issue with network up/down in kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I am trying to write a Linux kernel module that with the correct command, will bring down the the network interface (lets say wlan0) change its IP address to the one specified, then bring the interface back up. Before the comments begin, yes I know you can use ifconfig, and yes I know you can write user code to do this as well, however for my research project I am trying to learn how to do this in the Linux kernel.

After researching I found the `net_device` _ops struct which has the methods that I need to call for this (`ndo_stop`, and `ndo_open`). However I am struggling to find usage examples and thus tried:

```
dev->netdev_ops->ndo_stop(dev);
```

This compiled just fine, however when the module ran, the device was not brought down.

Can anyone provide a proper usage example or let me know what I am doing wrong?

```c
void targeted(int index, __u32 key){
    unsigned short cur_if;
    struct in_device *in_dev;
    struct in_ifaddr *if_info;
    struct net_device *dev;
    //struct net_device_ops ops;
    __be32 n_key;
    __u32 test2;
    test2 = 0x00FFFFFF;
    //test2 = test2 | key;
    n_key = cpu_to_be32(key);
    cur_if = 0;
    dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
    while (dev && cur_if < IFMAX) {
        in_dev = (struct in_device *)dev->ip_ptr;
        for (if_info = in_dev->ifa_list; if_info != NULL; if_info=if_info->ifa_next){
            if (cur_if == index){
                dev->netdev_ops->ndo_stop(dev);
                if_info->ifa_address = if_info->ifa_address & test2;
                if_info->ifa_local = if_info->ifa_local & test2;
                if_info->ifa_address = if_info->ifa_address | n_key;
                if_info->ifa_local = if_info->ifa_local | n_key;
                printk(KERN_DEBUG "New Test::: %pI4", &if_info->ifa_local);
                //dev->netdev_ops->ndo_open(dev);
            }   
        }
        cur_if++;
        dev = next_net_device(dev);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to that, what I am trying, in fact I try to achieve some kind of stealth mode, which should do this ( root is prerequisite). But it is not done via kernel-module. I still try to help. My steps should do this here:

1. stop all REAL ( no loopback, etc ) network devices
2. collect their macs
3. change their macs to unique random one
4. collect old hostname and change host  name to unique random one
5. reactivate the nics
6. set up some iptables,
7. all this as a daemon, waiting for special keycomobo to undo  all changes.

Let's go to the answer, or some kind of it:
The problem is, that You have for sure running some applications, wich are in control of Your nics, either via udev, or whatever. My example was WICD-daemon, which was running, and as soon as I turned off my nic in code, it was immediately turned on by wicd ( IIRC ).
I was googling and found some information about unloading the drivers..... but that also would mean, that we cannot change the macs or ip's anymore.
So in the kernel we need to identify, which userland-process occupies the nic.
It might be handy to kill those processes.
by the way, You can use the commands from above, which You mentioned, and prepend ptrace, then You will see, which syscalls are involved.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the advice! I'll have to take a look into that and see what comes of it.